# CSS/Javascript Scroll Replace Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to accomplish a couple things with JS/CSS that I can't figure out. Here's what I've got so far: http://codepen.io/melissall/pen/PPWPQE

1. I want the headline to be centered in the image until the text scrolls up.
2. I've got a CSS transition that changes the color of the text, but I don't want it to be timed, but based on the position of the headline. For an example of what I mean, check out how the logo changes color in this link: http://www.leaderbagco.com/

I've tried searching for examples, but I can't seem to find anything that helps. If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

There's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="container" class="row">
  <div id="heading" class="large-12">
    <h2>Heading lorem ipsum sit dolor</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="large-12">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nisi ante, pulvinar a lorem id, pellentesque facilisis diam. Cras placerat libero ut urna auctor faucibus. Morbi facilisis diam et massa facilisis, vel vulputate ex malesuada. Fusce varius, ex id vulputate accumsan, arcu orci scelerisque purus, et tempor orci leo et nisi. Aliquam aliquet massa vel nibh dictum viverra. Mauris dapibus quam ut magna congue porttitor. Aenean suscipit tortor a urna dapibus dignissim. In ornare risus et mauris pellentesque pharetra. Nunc et ultrices erat. Maecenas interdum dignissim turpis, in porta erat. Donec tortor urna, finibus ut quam ac, aliquam ullamcorper arcu. Vivamus id est quis ante volutpat laoreet. Proin fringilla pharetra est a sagittis. Fusce non magna mauris. Proin iaculis aliquet mi, a pellentesque dui porttitor ac. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h2{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
#image  {
  background: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/78/7039061-beautiful-tropical-beach-wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}
#heading{
  position: relative;
  top: -250px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;  
}
#heading h2{
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#heading h2.bgChange{
    color: #f00;

     -webkit-transition: color 1s;
       -moz-transition: color 1s;
        -ms-transition: color 1s;
         -o-transition: color 1s;
            transition: color 1s;
}
#content{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

JS

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#heading').followTo(490);

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var addRemClass = $(window).scrollTop() > 470 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    $("#heading h2")[addRemClass]('bgChange');
});
```

**EDIT #1:**

I've got it sort of working with just CSS, but have run into other issues. The new link is here: http://codepen.io/melissall/pen/pjRZdx

New Issue #1: The headline doesn't stick above the copy anymore. I had to remove the JS that was there because it was interfering with the heading positions.

<strike>New Issue #2: If you scroll down far enough, the white text that was on the image reappears.</strike>

**EDIT #2:**
Well I got it sorted (in CodePen at least) by adding some JS that detects when the page hits a certain point and changes the heading and copy to relative and absolute positions. And there's some other junk in there. The code is messy, and it still has flaws, but it functions in CodePen at the bare minimum of what I wanted to do. Here's the final code if anyone else is trying something similar: http://codepen.io/melissall/pen/pjRZdx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final code if anyone else is trying something similar: http://codepen.io/melissall/pen/pjRZdx

HTML

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="container" class="row">
  <h2 class="copy white large-9">Heading Here</h2>
    <div class="heading large-9">
        <h2 class="copy pink large-9">Heading Here</h2>
    </div>
  <div id="content" class="large-12">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nisi ante, pulvinar a lorem id, pellentesque facilisis diam. Cras placerat libero ut urna auctor faucibus. Morbi facilisis diam et massa facilisis, vel vulputate ex malesuada. Fusce varius, ex id vulputate accumsan, arcu orci scelerisque purus, et tempor orci leo et nisi. Aliquam aliquet massa vel nibh dictum viverra. Mauris dapibus quam ut magna congue porttitor. Aenean suscipit tortor a urna dapibus dignissim. In ornare risus et mauris pellentesque pharetra. Nunc et ultrices erat. Maecenas interdum dignissim turpis, in porta erat. Donec tortor urna, finibus ut quam ac, aliquam ullamcorper arcu. Vivamus id est quis ante volutpat laoreet. Proin fringilla pharetra est a sagittis. Fusce non magna mauris. Proin iaculis aliquet mi, a pellentesque dui porttitor ac. </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{}
h2{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
#image  {
  background: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/78/7039061-beautiful-tropical-beach-wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}
#content{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.heading {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
}
.copy.pink {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  color: pink;
}
.copy.white {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    color: white;    
}
.unstuck-copy{
  position: absolute !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: 0px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.unstuck-heading{
  position: relative !important;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

JS

```
// Hide the white text after scrolling past the image
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>350){
        $('.white').hide();
    }else{
        $('.white').show();
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('.heading').addClass('unstuck-heading');
        $('.copy.pink').addClass('unstuck-copy');
    } else {
        $('.heading').removeClass('unstuck-heading');
      $('.copy.pink').removeClass('unstuck-copy');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you heard about : Parallax? https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax

That website you mentioned use the same concept.

I checked the link you provided I can see its 2 images: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/3397/t/1/assets/leader-bag-co-bk.png?17257
http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/3397/t/1/assets/leader-bag-co-wh.png?17257

so basically he is not changing the logo color but the image instead.

see that website with top 50 parallax effects:
http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/parallax-scrolling-1131762

I hope my answer can help in something.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was trying to avoid parallax for this particular task and was hoping that there was an easy JS fix. I actually found a way of doing it with CSS that looks like it should work. I'll post something if I can get it working.

Comment: actually you can do without parallax plugin, just using jquery and css i can share a link about that if you want

Comment: I've edited my original post with a new sandbox, but am having different issues. If you're able to help or have a different solution, I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add some css styles and use jquery scroll to trigger the style if it meets the following condition.

```
body{}
h2{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  height: 5em;
}
#image  {
  background: url(http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/78/7039061-beautiful-tropical-beach-wallpaper.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}


#content{
  padding-top: 100px;
}


.heading {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
}

.copy.pink {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  color: pink;
}
/* Added this line to stick once its in the content */
.copy.pink.stick {
      position: static;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.copy.white {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    color: white;
}
/* Added this line to hide white copy once its in the content */
.copy.white.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
// Get distance of copy white from top
var whitedistance      = $('.copy.white').offset().top;
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  //Get distance of copy pink on top
  var wscrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
    pinkOffset = $('.heading').offset().top,
    pinkdistance      = (pinkOffset - wscrollTop);
  console.log(pinkdistance + " == " + whitedistance)
// if distance of pink is less than or equal the height and the white is still visible add class hidden to hide it.
  if(pinkdistance <= whitedistance && !$('.copy.white').hasClass('hidden') ){
    console.log('hidden');
    $( ".copy.white" ).addClass( "hidden" );
    $( ".copy.pink" ).addClass( "stick" );
  }
  else if(pinkdistance > whitedistance && $('.copy.white').hasClass('hidden')){
// Display copy white again once the distance of copy pink is higher again than the white
    $( ".copy.white" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
    $( ".copy.pink" ).removeClass( "stick" );
  }
});
```

Hope this works. :)